# Can't send/receive UDP communication between two Docker containers on Mac OS Host

Tags: docker, udp, containers, udpclient, docker-for-mac

I'm running Docker Desktop for Mac on host, it is running two containers.

- **Container-1:** linux-based OS, running UDP-based server program listening on 14xxx port (`udp://:14xxx/`).
- **Container-2:** linux-based OS, python application sending/receiving data via UDP address as `udp://14xxx/` without any specific hostname.

**Question**: My python app on Container-2 is able to send on UDP port, but never receives anything back from Container-1.

Given UDP works differently from TCP & HTTP protocols..

### How can I establish successful UDP communication between two docker containers running on same host (MacOS)?

**Various things** that I have tried, but no luck.

1. Tried running both containers using `--network host` option.
2. Tried creating a new docker network `testnet` and started containers using `--network testnet` option.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found the solution.

First, it was not a docker thing at all.

In my python application on **Container-2**, I used environment variables to determine the UDP address. Apparently, these variables were not set properly. Hence, the confusion/error.

Second, "--network host" is still a VALID argument to have for both running Docker containers to make sure they discover/talk to each other.

Hope it helps!